# Virtual Hosting on Next.js app with Apollo GraphQL

Tags: apollo, next.js, apollo-client

I have a webapp made with Next.js and Apollo as show in example [with-apollo](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo). I want to serve multiple domains with my webapp (name-based virtual hosting). Unfortunately `HttpLink` of `ApolloClient` requires [absolute server URL](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/c6393b498820b8d8b0f6b43844c1778d20a57f6b/examples/with-apollo/lib/apollo.js#L131) with domain but this makes backend app unable to recognize domain which user really visited. Is there a way to configure `HttpLink` with a dynamic URL based on real request or use relative URL or anything else?

Comment: I don't understand why " absolute server URL with domain but this makes backend app unable to recognize domain which user really visited"

Comment: absolule url doesn't indicate that url has to be immutable string

Comment: It means url should contain protocol , domain and path

Comment: what  backend you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Either use an Apollo Link to intercept the query and set uri property on the context

```
const authMiddleware = setContext((operation, { uri }) => {
  return refreshToken().then(res => ({
    uri: this.getURI()
  })
}))
```

Or intercept the request with Angular's HttpClient interceptor and change the endpoint.

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-angular/tree/master/packages/apollo-angular-link-http#options

Source: [Updating uri of apollo client instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51112677/updating-uri-of-apollo-client-instance)

Answer (score 0):

The `NextPageContext` object passed to `getInitialProps` includes the `req` object when called on the server-side. So you can do something like:

```
WithApollo.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  const { AppTree, req } = ctx

  const linkBaseUrl = req ? req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') : ''

  ...
}
```

You can then pass this base url down to `createApolloClient` along with the initial state and prepend your HttpLink's url with it. On the client side, this will prepend an empty string (you only need the full URL on the server).